# 「吉里吉里2 SDK version 2.32 revision 2」のファイル構成について

Tags: c++, 吉里吉里

**どの部分が C++ ？**
・[ここ](http://kikyou.info/tvp/)から「kr2_232r2.zip」をダウンロードしました
・[Wiki](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%90%89%E9%87%8C%E5%90%89%E9%87%8C2)にはプログラミング言語   C++と書かれているのですが、どのファイルが該当するのでしょうか？
・ネットで検索したら、C++の拡張子は、 "cc"、"cp"、"cpp"、"cxx" と書かれていたのですが、ファイルが同梱されていません
・C++で記述した内容をコンパイルした結果が、krkr.eXeという意味でしょうか？

---

**どの部分が 吉里吉里 ？**

> 吉里吉里は、TJSと呼ばれるスクリプト言語の実行環境である

・意味が分からないのですが、吉里吉里とはkrkr.eXeのことですか？
・それとも、kirikiri2フォルダにある内容全て(krkr.eXe + *.tjs)が、吉里吉里？
・つまり、吉里吉里は「exe本体 + tjs」を意味する言葉？

---

**吉里吉里2 SDK**
・kag3フォルダを同梱しているから、SDKと呼んでいるのでしょうか？

---

**技術的なことについて**
・kirikiri2フォルダに関して言えば、tjsスクリプトを学習すれば良い？
・eXeファイルは内容確認しようがないため、学習しようがない？
・dllはexeをWindows環境で動作させるために必要なものであまり気にする必要はない？ これは何の言語ですか？

Comment: 質問の数が多すぎると思います。意味的に1つの質問になるように調整してくださいませんでしょうか。そうでないと不必要に回答が長くなりますし、検索性も落ちてしまいます。意味的に連続していそうな部分のみ回答しましたので、これで残りの疑問点が解決しなければ、他の方の回答を待つか、その部分を別個の質問として投稿して頂くのが良いのではないかと思います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### どの部分がC++？

kr2_232r2.zip に含まれているのは、ソースコードからコンパイルされて出来た実行ファイル (kirikiri2/krkr.eXe など) とライブラリです。ソースコードは含まれていません。

吉里吉里2のソースコードは [Subversion で管理されています](https://sv.kikyou.info/trac/kirikiri/wiki/AboutSubversion)。このリンク先からアクセスできるリポジトリを閲覧してソースコードを見れば、C++ のファイル (*.cpp) が多数あることが確認できます。

#### どの部分が吉里吉里？

「TJS」というのは吉里吉里のために作られたプログラミング言語の名前で、「吉里吉里」という処理系を使って、TJS で書かれたプログラムを実行できます。プログラミング言語とその処理系を区別してください。他の言語の例を出すと、たとえば、[SpiderMonkey](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpiderMonkey) は [JavaScript](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) の処理系です。

#### 「吉里吉里2 SDK」とはどういう意味？

SDK は[「ソフトウェア開発キット」 (Software Development Kit)](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%BD%E3%83%95%E3%83%88%E3%82%A6%E3%82%A7%E3%82%A2%E9%96%8B%E7%99%BA%E3%82%AD%E3%83%83%E3%83%88) の略です。KAG や、kirikiri2/tools/ にあるものなど、吉里吉里2でソフトウェア開発するために必要なツールが入ったもの、という意味でそう命名しているのではないかと思います。

Answer (score 4):

あなたがどんな立場にいるのかで学ぶべき内容は異なってくると思いますが。

あなたがダウンロードしたファイルは吉里吉里2を使ってゲームを作ろうとしているゲームデベロッパのためのものです。あなたの目的が吉里吉里2を使ってゲームを作ることであるのなら `TJS` を学んでゲームシナリオを書けばよくて、吉里吉里2が何で書かれているかを気にする必要はありません。

吉里吉里2が何か、ということなら Visual Studio を思えばよいでしょう。Visual Studio をダウンロードしたユーザは Visual Studio 自体が何言語で書かれているかを気にすることなく C# でも C++ でも VB でも、自分の書きたい言語を書けばよいわけで、この辺の事情は吉里吉里2にもそのまま適用できます。

あなたが吉里吉里2をメンテナンスしたいと思っている（吉里吉里2自体のデベロッパになりたい）のであれば、下記のことを知っておく必要があるでしょう。

`krkr.exe` (および付属 DLL 群) は `C++` で書かれています。
`krkr.exe` のソースコードは別途提供されています。
https://sv.kikyou.info/trac/kirikiri/wiki/AboutSubversion
古いソフトウエアであって更新されていないので、コンパイル環境を整えるだけで一苦労すると思います。

まあ今はより新しいソフトとして吉里吉里Zの開発が行われているというか停滞しているというか、そういう状況なので、吉里吉里のメンテナになりたいのであれば吉里吉里Zのほうをよろしくお願いしたいというところです。
http://krkrz.github.io/